# Hidden files wont stay hidden in Ubuntu Gnome

Tags: gnome, hidden-files, ubuntu-gnome

Whenever I open the Home folder, all the hidden files are displayed along with unhidden files. I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> and they disappear, but they are visible again when I open Home again. I've tried de-selecting "Show Hidden Files" from the dropdown menu, but it has the same result. I'm using Ubuntu Gnome 13.10.

Comment: Menu -> File -> Preferences -> Views -. Show Hidden and Backup files.

Comment: crafter, these selections are not available in Ubuntu Gnome.

Comment: @BradL Did you find solution? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 8):

Open the **Files** app (a.k.a. Nautilus), open the Files `Menu`, click on `Preferences`, in the Views tab **uncheck** `Show hidden and backup files`. Close the Preferences and the Files window, and open a new one, now by default you won't see hidden files.

[image: hide hidden files Files app]