# how to hide files using ubuntu GNOME

Tags: gnome, hidden-files

Does renaming file with a name which starts with a dot hides files in ubuntu GNOME.
I have done the same but whenever i restart nautilus the hidden files reappear is this a bug

Comment: Try renaming files using the terminal. eg --- mv filename.txt   .filename.txt

Comment: Can you please flag this question as solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You toggle on/off between "Show Hidden Files"/"Hide Hidden Files" using CTRL + H. Toggle it off by pressing Ctrl + H and then restart your PC. Now, do you see your hidden files anymore? Please comment.

Comment: yes i do see them

Comment: Have you tried this? http://askubuntu.com/questions/371253/hidden-files-wont-stay-hidden-in-ubuntu-gnome

Comment: Glad it helped! :-)